# c - Unable to write data to a file from inside a child process

Tags: c, file, fork, parent-child

I have two furnctions in a c program, `create_open_log_file()` and `write_to_log_file()` and a global file pointer.

When these functions get called, the log file is created as expected (I can see it in the dir). Then `write_to_log_file()` is called and a child process is created. At this point I would have expected that the string `test test test` would be written to this file in a loop. The string `child process` is printed on the terminal o I know the code is being excuted. However, the log file has no content?

I'd appreicate if somebody could tell me if I am doing something obvious wrong.

```
FILE *log_file;

static void create_open_log_file(void) {

char filename[40];
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
char s[64];
strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%a%b%d%T", tm);
sprintf(filename, "dut1_serial_log_%s", s);

log_file = fopen(filename,"w");

if (log_file == NULL) {
    perror("Error creating log file");
}

}




static write_to_log_file() {


// Prevent killed child-processes remaining as "defunct"
struct sigaction sigchld_action = {
        .sa_handler = SIG_DFL,
        .sa_flags = SA_NOCLDWAIT
};
sigaction( SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL ) ;


// Duplicate ("fork") the process. Will return zero in the child
// process, and the child's PID in the parent (or negative on error).
int pid = fork();
global_pid = pid;
if( pid < 0 ) {
    printf( "Fork failed\n" ) ;
    return 1 ;
}


// ------------ Child process
if( pid == 0 ) {
    // ------------ Child process

    // Open log file and write to it from /dev/USB1

    create_open_log_file();

    while( 1 ) {
        printf( "child process\n" ) ;

        char str[] = "test test test";

        fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , log_file);


        sleep(1) ;
    }
    return 0 ; //never reached
}
}
```

Comment: Please clean up the code's indention. Didn't the preview work for you?

Comment: Try [*flushing*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) the buffers of the file.

Comment: @alk sorry - fixed now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - thanks that was it flushing the buffer.

Comment: @articsol:  "*fixed now*" not really ...

Answer (score 2):

From a quick code review, it looks like the child process never closes the file, hence the data may or may not reach the file.

Ah.  Since it is an infinite loop you really don't intend a close.   Yes.  Flushing the buffer will generally get the data all the way to the disk, which is what I am guessing is what you are really after.

Answer (score 2):

Flushing a `FILE` is needed; otherwise your output just sits in memory (the file's buffer block) till the block is filled up, or you `fclose` the file pointer. That's part of the difference between buffered stdio, and bare file handles.